# Convert data with escaped unicode characters to string

Tags: swift

I receive strings from web api with escaped unicode characters like that: `Pla\u010daj Izbri\u0161i`.

```
public func decode(data: Data) throws -> String {
    guard let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw SomeError()
    }

    // text = Pla\u010daj Izbri\u0161i
}
```

What is the best way to convert it to normal displayable unicode string?

Comment: Is that part of a JSON response? In that case the JSONDecoder should handle it automatically.

Comment: No, it is not a part of JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `data` has the same content as something like this:

```
let data = #"Pla\u010daj Izbri\u0161i"#.data(using: .utf8)!
print(data as NSData) //->{length = 24, bytes = 0x506c615c7530313064616a20497a6272695c753031363169}
```

You can decode it in this way:

```
    public func decode(data: Data) throws -> String {
        guard let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw SomeError()
        }

        let transform = StringTransform(rawValue: "Any-Hex/Java")
        return text.applyingTransform(transform, reverse: true) ?? text
    }
```

---

But, if you really get this sort of data from the web api, you should better tell the api engineer to use some normal encoding scheme.

Comment: `\uNNNN` is a typical JSON escape sequence, so I wonder if that data is actually part of some JSON response.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, that's one possibility. Though, it's not sure. So, I clarified this answer is based on an assumption.